# load Font awsomes icons in a client side component nextjs 13.4

Tags: reactjs, next.js, font-awesome, next.js13

I am using Next.js with its new app Server-Side Rendering (SSR) model and I want to know how to correctly load icons in client-side components. When I try to use an icon, like <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'home']} />, I get an error message "Could not find icon { prefix: 'fas', iconName: 'home' }". I assume the issue is because config/assets are loaded only on server-side components, not client-side ones. I am using "fortawesome/react-fontawesome" to render the icons, as is recommended in the FontAwesome setup, and it works successfully in server-side components. FA is configured in the `layout.tsx` file as follows:

```js
import { config, library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons'; 
import { fal } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons'; 

config.autoAddCss = false; 
library.add(fas, fal);
```

What kind of config do I need to load in the client components? I want to avoid importing icons manually in every location. I have tried dumping all the imports into a client-side component but this bloats the app by bundling FA everywhere.

Comment: If you are using a client side component, you have to ship the icon to the client side. The options you have are to individually import icons, bundle the whole library or use the cdn version.  The next.js attitude is to try to use server components at all times. Unless the icon is changing based on user input or is being animated, you could probably refactor to isolate the client side behaviour and keep the static assets static. If you post the component's code we can take a look.